# Display updated values nested in a a loop, and iterating over a dynamic list Python

Tags: python, loops, dynamic, nested

I am currently writing a small python program to watch my current trades at 1Broker.com using their API, it should list any open positions, number them using a counter, and then update the chosen stats (P/L percent and position_id) on each run through, after a sleep timer.

I was working in a dirty early draft, however decided to "optimize" and clean my code... and broke it.
Here is a snippit of the erroneous section:

```
if self.total_open_positions != []:
        counter = int("0")
        for position in self.total_open_positions:
            counter += 1
            display =  {}
            display["Open Order"] = str(counter)
            display["ID"] = str(position["position_id"])
            display["P/L Percent"] = str(position["profit_loss_percent"])                           
            print display
            time.sleep(timer - ((time.time() - starttime) % timer))
        if self.total_positions == []:
            print "All trades closed"
```

The data in P/L percent and ID refuse to update on each loop through.

Thank you in advance to anyone who helps :)

By "refuse to update" I mean when the program is run, it retrieves the P/L percent as desired. However each consecutive loop prints the same P/L percentage. Meaning the value of str(position["profit_loss_percent"]) hasnt updated to the most recent data retrieved from the website. (eg. shows 3%, when the trade is now up to 6%)

[image]
The left image is 1st draft. However, it you look, the P/L% chages through each iteration. whereas in the right image it stays the same.

As for self.total_open_positions, it is equal to my api request:
`self.total_open_positions = requests.get(API_URL)`

heres a snippet of the "dirty" version that at least works properly, maybe it will help show my intentions, and my noob-level skill (which is why i need help lol):

```
total_open_orders = open_orders["response"]
while total_open_orders == []:
    print "Checking again......"
    time.sleep(timer1 - ((time.time() - starttime) % timer1))
else:
    #When orders are found, loop through and display
    while True:
        #Wait desired time between refreshing stats
        time.sleep(timer1 - ((time.time() - starttime) % timer1))
        #Position number (oldest first)
        counter = 0
        ##Print a small seperator between refreshes
        print "#" * 20
        #Loop through list of positions and print stats for each
        for order in total_open_orders:
            #Add to counter for each position
            counter += 1
            #Display stats to user (anything in '[]' is JSON format
            try:
                print "#" * 40
                print "Open Order #: " + str(counter)
                print "ID #:         " + str(order["position_id"])
                print "Market:       " + str(order["symbol"])
                print "Entry:        " + str(order["entry_price"])
                print "Stop Loss:    " + str(order["stop_loss"])
                print "Take Profit:  " + str(order["take_profit"])
                print "P/L:  " + str(order["profit_loss_percent"])
                print "#" * 40
                print ""
            #Catch any connection errors and print for debugging
            except Exception as e:
                print e
```

Comment: What do you mean refuse to update? Can you show an example output - and what you are expecting. You really don't need `if self.total_open_positions != []:` before the for loop. And any reason not to do `counter = 0` vs `int("0")`

Comment: Where does it throw a `None-type` error?

Comment: because the requested data is a json object, if there are no open trades, response = [None]. this causes any attempts to grab ID and P/L to error out because at that time they dont exist

Comment: But if it is an empty list the `for` loop will never enter. Which is why I would believe the test for an empty list is superfluous.

Comment: `int("0")` is hilarious!

Comment: lol maybe so, but it works. it will be changed eventually, once all else is working.

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you expect and what you get. Your description is not clear as it stands. Also it would be good to explain how self.total_open_positions gets updated. It seems to me that since you are having a timer in the `for` loop because you are waiting for something to update (the positions perhaps?). But updating the list/dict you are iterating on, **while running the iteration** is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved. Because self.total_open_positions was defined in a function above, it was only called once and therefore only got one set of stats. by having total_open_positions redefined within the scope of my loop, all data is properly displayed :)